# Angular material input field dynamic width

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to make a material form field have a dynamic width. The field is a disabled field and should only be dynamic in the way that the bound string will determine the length of the field when the page loads.

I found this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-dynamic-width) and tried to rework it to fix my problem but could not find a way to make it work.

This is my forked [version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-field-dynamic-width?file=app%2Finput-text-width-example.ts) of it.

Answer (score 0):

On your version you just forgot to add `(input)=resizeInput()`, with it, it works perfectly.

Moreover, if you don't add the `setTimeout` function, the resize of the input is not smooth. In the example, there is a comment that said that

> without setTimeout the width gets updated to the previous length

So I suggest you to keep it.

Finally this works in your code :

```
resizeInput(newInputWidth: string) {
  setTimeout ( () =>{
    const minWidth = 64;
    if (this.invisibleTextER.nativeElement.offsetWidth > minWidth) {
      this.width = this.invisibleTextER.nativeElement.offsetWidth + 2;
    } else {
      this.width = minWidth;
    }
  }, 0);
}
```